# Sum two primefaces input fileds into another

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I want to take the input from two input fields and simultaneous compute the sum into another input field (total) that must be editable however. I tried like that (I cutted away some code useless to the question):

```
<p:inputText id="field1"
    value="#{ModelBean.object.field1}"
    onkeydown="#{BackingBean.updateTotal()}">
</p:inputText>

<p:selectOneMenu id="field2" required="true"
    value="#{ModelBean.object.field2}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="22 %" itemValue="22" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="10 %" itemValue="10" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="4 %" itemValue="4" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="0 %" itemValue="0" />
</p:selectOneMenu>


<!-- TOTAL -->

<p:inputText id="total"
    value="#{ModelBean.object.total}">
</p:inputText>
```

As you can see I delegated tho BackingBean.update() method the compute task. It updates the total value and set it into the total field of the bean. The problem that I saw in debug is that the values of my two fields to sum is null. How I can do to let the model variables filled while I am writing? And What I have to modify to let the result of the compute immediately written in the total input filed?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than this you can use Ajax for this:

```
 <p:inputText id="field1" value="#{ModelBean.object.field1}">
          <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="total" listener="#{BackingBean.updateTotal}"></ajax>
 </p:inputText>

 <p:selectOneMenu id="field2" required="true"
          value="#{ModelBean.object.field2}">
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="22 %" itemValue="22" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="10 %" itemValue="10" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="4 %" itemValue="4" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="0 %" itemValue="0" />
          <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="total" listener="#{BackingBean.updateTotal}"></ajax>
 </p:selectOneMenu>


<!-- TOTAL -->

 <p:inputText id="total" value="#{ModelBean.object.total}">
 </p:inputText>
```

I think you need to put ajax in both components, because to are getting sum on the basis of values of both. And if you don't want to use  "Change" event than you can use some other event of ajax.

Answer (score 1):

1. create project and include it

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
      <h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputText value="Keyup: " />
        <p:inputText id="counter2" value="#{listenerView.a}">   
            <p:ajax event="keyup" update="out" listener="#{listenerView.handleKeyEvent}"/>
        </p:inputText>
        <p:inputText id="counter" value="#{listenerView.b}">
            <p:ajax event="keyup" update="out" listener="#{listenerView.handleKeyEvent}" />
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputText id="out" value="#{listenerView.c}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

```js
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.ajax;
 
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
 
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ListenerView {
     
    private String text;
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
 
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
     
    public void handleKeyEvent() {
        c=a+b;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(int c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Example @FaridAhmed!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the inserted value on the *server side* to do some calculations, you have to (partially) submit the form first. You may do this via AJAX like this:

```
<p:inputText id="field1"
    value="#{ModelBean.object.field1}">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{BackingBean.updateTotal}" update="total"/>
</p:inputText>

<p:selectOneMenu id="field2" required="true"
    value="#{ModelBean.object.field2}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="22 %" itemValue="22" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="10 %" itemValue="10" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="4 %" itemValue="4" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="0 %" itemValue="0" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{BackingBean.updateTotal}" update="total"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<!-- TOTAL -->
<p:inputText id="total"
    value="#{ModelBean.object.total}">
</p:inputText>
```

If all information which is required for the calculation is available on the current view and the calculation is quite easy, like it seems to be here, you may also consider to do the job completely on the client side via plain JavaScript.